# Что означает это предупреждение google colab после компиляции

Tags: python, tensorflow

```
#Импорт TensorFlow и других библиотек
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import os
import PIL
import tensorflow as tf

from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential

#загружаем датасет
import pathlib
dataset_url = "https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1Qy0ZOMXZAlDz8gAaDf6OKnB-iwHIjPv3?usp=sharing"
data_dir = tf.keras.utils.get_file('infarct', origin=dataset_url, untar=True)
data_dir = pathlib.Path(data_dir)
```

---

```
Downloading data from https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1Qy0ZOMXZAlDz8gAaDf6OKnB-iwHIjPv3?usp=sharing
  98304/Unknown - 0s 1us/step
```

В итоге загрузка папок с изображениями по ссылке была осуществлена? Или в чём причина, если не получилось. Я не до конца осознаю что писать в data_dir для импорта файла с изображениями с гугл диска. Следую примеру https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/images/classification

Answer (score 1):

Это не предупреждение, а индикатор загрузки. Посмотрим, что получается в `data_dir` после загрузки:

```
data_dir = tf.keras.utils.get_file('infarct', origin=dataset_url, untar=True)
print(data_dir)
 
/root/.keras/datasets/infarct
```

Попробуем посмотреть, есть ли такой файл:

```
!ls -la /root/.keras/datasets/infarct

ls: cannot access '/root/.keras/datasets/infarct': No such file or directory
```

Хм. А если так:

```
!ls -la /root/.keras/datasets/

total 236
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root   4096 Mar 18 05:28 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root   4096 Mar 18 05:28 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 229973 Mar 18 05:28 infarct.tar.gz
```

Ага, вот оно. Если я всё правильно понимаю, файл с данными у вас загрузился в такой файл колаба:

```
/root/.keras/datasets/infarct.tar.gz
```